# Unwanted faint lines connecting dashed double line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Building on the answer [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304044/103076](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqj2o.png) by wrtlprnft, I have the following code

```
   \documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{arrowed double line}=[
            dashed, double distance between line centers=3pt,
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 10pt and -10pt step 20pt with {
                    \arrow[thin,yshift= 1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{>}
                    \arrow[thin,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{<}
                },
            },
        ]
        \draw[arrowed double line] (0,0) --  (1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I am unhappy with the faint transverse lines between the dashes. I don't even know why tikz decides to draw them.

Is there a way to get rid of them?

Thanks in advance to all replies.

PS the same thing occurs at the caps of double solid lines

Comment: i'm not a regular user of tikz, so this is just a guess.  this could be an artifact from drawing a thick line, then blanking out the center portion.  someone who is more familiar with the tikz internals could confirm or refute this.

Comment: Probably a problem with the anti-aliasing, see also the comments on this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251562/82624

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes. All double lines are really one line on top of a thicker one, if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments.  That's interesting. Then I believe the only solution would be to redraw everything with a method that doesn't cause this.

Comment: @cfr -- yes, that's exactly what i had in mind.  thanks for checking.  what would happen if this were on a colored background?  presumably, the overlay line could be drawn in the background color, but is it?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not by default, but you can change the colour used for the second line.

Comment: @Mercan You can draw each bit separately e.g. draw the dashed lines. Then draw a thinner, non-dashed line down the middle. Then use a decorated path to add the arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [arrowed double line/.style={% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  preaction={
    draw=black,
    dashed,
    double distance between line centers=3pt,
    line width=.4pt,
  },
  draw=white,
  line width=3pt,
  postaction={
    decorate,
  },
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 10pt and -10pt step 20pt with {
      \arrow [thin,black,yshift= 1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{>}
      \arrow [thin,black,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{<}
    },
  },
  }]
  \path[arrowed double line] (0,0) --  (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: manual construction]

## EDIT

If you want to remove traces at the ends of the lines, you can use `shorten` with a negative dimension for just the white line. Obviously, this needs a little care to avoid painting over anything already in the picture.

For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [arrowed double line/.style={% \tikzstyle is deprecated
    preaction={
      draw=black,
      dashed,
      double distance between line centers=3pt,
      line width=.4pt,
      shorten >=0pt,
      shorten <=0pt,
    },
    draw=white,
    line width=3pt,
    shorten >=-.1pt,
    shorten <=-.1pt,
    postaction={
      decorate,
    },
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 10pt and -10pt step 20pt with {
        \arrow [thin,black,yshift= 1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{>}
        \arrow [thin,black,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=.8pt]{<}
      },
    },
  }]
  \path[arrowed double line] (0,0) --  (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the following line ending:

[image: end of line]

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much. I wasn't sure if that white band was at all possible. Is it possible to extend it a little such that the caps go away as well?

Comment: You can use `shorten >=` and `shorten <=` with negative values for the white line. That should probably work, but you'd need to be careful to avoid painting over anything in the way, of course!

Comment: @Mercan Please see edit.