# Quiver with abbreviating arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to draw a quiver with abbreviated arrows like 
[image: quiver]

I tried the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
1 
\arrow[rrrr, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description

\arrow[rrrr, bend left,        "x_0"]
\arrow[rrrr, bend right, swap, "x_m"]
\arrow[ddrr, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description]
\arrow[ddrr, bend left,        "y_{0}"]
\arrow[ddrr, bend right, swap, "y_n"]
&&&& 3
   \\
   \\
&&2
\arrow[uurr]
\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

but the output is not satisfactory. I was wondering if I there is anyway to change the 'bend left/right' to something that suits better for the presentation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably want `shift` rather than `bend`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd avoid symmetric shifting (not bending anyhow), so the arrows won't overlap. Some tweaking of the positions for the labels is necessary.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\svdots}{%
  \vbox{%
    \scriptsize
    \baselineskip 2\p@
    \lineskiplimit \z@
    \hbox {.}\hbox {.}\hbox {.}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=huge]
1
\arrow[rr,shift left=2ex,"x_0"]
\arrow[rr,"\svdots","x_m" swap]
\arrow[dr,"y_{0}" pos=0.45]
\arrow[dr,shift right=2ex,"\svdots" {sloped,pos=0.4},"y_n" swap]
&& 3
   \\
&2 \arrow[ur]
\\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this is what you had in mind

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip3\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes = {inner sep = 9pt, row sep = 40pt},
lbl/.style={anchor = south, rotate = -50}]
1 
\arrow[rr, shift right = 2ex, "x_n"'] 
\arrow[rr, shift left = 2ex, "x_1", "\rvdots"'] 
\arrow[rd, shift left = 1ex, "y_n"] 
\arrow[rd, shift right = 3ex, "y_1"', "\rvdots" lbl] 
& & 3 \\
& 2 
\arrow[ru] 
& 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Really just for fun a proposal that makes use of the fact that the commutative diagrams are essentially Ti*k*Z matrices of nodes (see section 3.3 of the manual) and @cfr's nice double arrow trick.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrowed double line/.style={% inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321759/121799
  preaction={
    draw=black,line width=0.5pt,
    double distance between line centers=#1,
  },
   draw=white,
    line width={#1-1pt},
    shorten >=-.5pt,
    shorten <=-.5pt,
  postaction={
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 1 with {
      \arrow[line width=0.5pt,black,yshift=#1/2]{>}
      \arrow[line width=0.5pt,black,yshift=-#1/2]{>}
    },
  },
    decorate,
  },
  }
} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, name=m, commutative diagrams/every cell] {
1 & \hspace*{2cm}&3 \\[1.8cm] &2 &\\};
\draw[arrowed double line=3mm] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-3) 
node[midway,above=3pt,inner sep=0pt] (x1) {$x_1$} node[midway,below=3pt,inner sep=0pt] (xn) {$x_n$};
\draw[arrowed double line=3mm] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-2) 
node[sloped,midway,above=3pt,inner sep=0pt] (y1) {$y_1$} 
node[sloped,midway,below=3pt,inner sep=0pt] (yn) {$y_n$};
\draw[->] (m-1-3) -- (m-2-2);
\draw[dotted,thick] (x1) -- (xn);
\draw[dotted,thick] (y1) -- (yn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I said, just for fun.